# Java Class's property not getting set when passing through parameter

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

I have two classes
here's code

```
    public class LoginServiceImplementation implements LoginService {
    public boolean validateLogin(Login login)
    {
        LoginDao loginDao=DaoFactory.getLoginDao();
            boolean b=loginDao.validateLogin(login);
       System.out.println("id=="+login.getLoginId()+" uname=="+login.getuName()+" pass== "+login.getPassword());//  values reset to null
return b;
    }
}




    public class LoginDaoImplementation implements LoginDao {

    @Override
    public Login validateLogin(Login login) {   
        Session session= Hibernate.getHibernateSession();
        Query query= session.createQuery("from Login where uName= 'user' and password= 123");
        //query.setParameter("uname", login.getuName());
        //query.setParameter("pwd", login.getPassword());
        //System.out.print(login.getuName());
        //System.out.print(login.getPassword());
        try
        {
            List<Login> logins=query.list();
            System.out.print(logins.size());

            if(logins.size()>0)
            {
                Login l=new Login();
                l=logins.get(0);
                login=l;                
                System.out.println("id=="+login.getLoginId()+" uname=="+login.getuName()+" pass== "+login.getPassword());/// ALL values getting printed
                return login;
            }
            session.close();
            return null;
        }
        catch(HibernateException x)
        {
            x.printStackTrace();
            session.close();
            return null;
        }

    }


}
```

when calling validatemethod of DaoImplementation class from serviceImplementation class, DaoImplementation class sets the values in the login object which is passed as parameter, but in serviceimplementation class i'm getting same old object with all values set to null.
Please reply with reason and solution.
thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
 login=l;
```

That does not work. You are just assigning a new object to the local variable `login`. This has no effect on the object that was previously stored in that variable (and that is visible to the outside world). Java does not support pass-by-reference, so you cannot re-assign variables outside of your scope.

You need to either copy all the data into that object (using setters), or (my preference) return a Login object from the method that the caller can use. (It is not clear if you are already doing that, part of the sample seems to return `boolean`, part seems to return a `Login` object).